# Error: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model called `Group`, and another called `Reply` that contains an attribute which is a foreignkey to `Group`. This attribute is named `which_group`.

Next, to a queryset of Group objects, I annotated a related object called **latest**, which is simply the `Max(reply__id)` related to each object. This resulting queryset I called **groups**.

Next I did the following:

```
 values = tuple([(group.id, group.latest) for group in groups])
 replies = Reply.objects.extra(where=['(which_group_id,id) IN %s' % (values)])
 replies = list(replies)
 return replies
```

I tested this code with a user who had 1 object in **groups**. It returned me an error:

**operator does not exist: record = integer
LINE 1: ...se" FROM "links_reply" WHERE ((which_group_id,id) IN (1, 52)...
                                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.**

How do I fix this?

*p.s. my DB is Postgres (it's known to be "strongly typed")*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it will be easier to achieve your goal using different query instead of dealing with sql casting and extra statement. If you need to get replies that grouped by which_group_id value and has max(id) for it's group then you need to try this query

```
Reply.objects.values('which_group_id').annotate(Max('id'))
```

UPDATED: 
If you need the list containing the latest reply for every group object what you need is:

```
>>> ids = Reply.objects.values('which_group_id').annotate(Max('id'))
                                                .values_list('id__max', flat=True)
>>> replies = Reply.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

Comment: Yea I've begun looking at alternatives. Actually what I need is: annotating the ID of the **latest reply** (regardless of who wrote it) with each group object.

Comment: @HassanBaig So do you need the list of all groups with annotated latest reply or list of latest replies for each group?

Comment: Nick, I can handle both, I began with wanting the former, ended with very nearly approximating the latter. I suppose for the sake of sticking as close to this question as possible, let's say I need **a list containing the latest reply for every group object**

Comment: @HassanBaig I've updated my answer to meet your goal.

Comment: Dude, you're a champ. Awesome!

Comment: A quick followup - what to do in case I need to limit the replies to the 60 latest replies in groups. Should I add merely `[:60]` at the end of the first statement in your update?

Comment: To be sure, I'm looking for 60 latest replies such that each reply ought to be a latest reply in a group. I.e., all replies must correspond to **distinct groups**. What I don't need is 60 latest replies, 50 of which (for example), appeared in the same group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95139/discussion-between-nick-and-hassan-baig).

Answer (score 0):

Can be mistaken, but your problem is caused by your IN clause.

(which_group_id,id) is an incorrect expression in terms of SQL. Split it to 2 AND clauses, e.g.: which_group_id IN [values_list] AND id IN [values_list]

Comment: I did this: `replies = Reply.objects.extra(where=['which_group_id IN %s AND id IN %s ' % (values)])`. I now get: **not enough arguments for format string**

Comment: sure; 'cause you have 2 placeholders %s. So, you have to do:
    'which_group_id IN %s AND id IN %s ' % (values, values)

or 

'which_group_id IN %(values)s AND id IN %(values)s ' % {'values': values}

Comment: `values` is a list of tuple objects. Shouldn't statements like `id IN (values)s` not compute since it's comparing a singular variable to a tuple?

Comment: according to the docs the correct syntax of IN command is: `value IN (value1,value2,...)` So, the correct SQL command will be: `'which_group_id IN (1, 2, 3)'`. When you try to apply tuple substitution (e.g.: `values = (1, 2, 3)`) you will get the same result. You can try it using python command in terminal. `values = (1, 2, 3)` `'which_group_id IN %s AND id IN %s ' % (values, values)` Result: 'which_group_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND id IN (1, 2, 3) '

Comment: Well, in my case values is more like so: `values = ((1,52),(2,55),(6,45),(10,2))`, i.e. a list of tuples. Now imagine `which_group_id = 1`, `id=55`. If we write `id IN values` or `which_group_id IN values`, it will try to find 1 (or 55) among a list of tuples. Shouldn't that give a syntax error?

Comment: Ok, caught the idea :) So, in case of tuples according to the official docs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-subquery.html#AEN16806 you have to build row_constructor. In PostgreSQL it's built with ROW key word: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS So, I believe you have just to modify your template where string to `'ROW(which_group_id,id) IN %s'`

Comment: Ultimately, that too leads me to the error: **operator does not exist: record = integer**. I think it's squarely a type casting issue. ROW ensures there's no synxtax problem here whatsoever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95125/discussion-between-dmitry-and-hassan-baig).